# How to compile a ".pc" file on Debian 9?

Tags: debian, compiling, database, sql, oracle

I need to compile a [Pro*C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pro*C) - `.pc` file on Ubuntu.

So far what I have realised is that I need a Pro*C compiler to translate the Pro*C - `.pc` file into pure / standard C code. 
But I need to have Oracle DB installed for doing that.

I'm confused with the procedures on internet and some say that there's no .deb package of Oracle at all which means it is not available for Ubuntu.

Where do I get this Pro*C compiler from? Is there any better way to install it separately without installing Oracle DB or any such workaround?

Comment: It's a pro*c file which contains embedded sql commands

Comment: Ah, I see.  I just hadn't heard of it.

Comment: You may look for the pre-compiler starting from here: https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/11g/r2/prod/appdev/proc/proc.htm

Comment: Note that the pre-compiler needs the connection to an Oracle DB which contains the tables you use in the pc queries you have to pre-compile.

Answer (score 2):

You may look for the pre-compiler starting from here:

https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/11g/r2/prod/appdev/proc/proc.htm

Note that the pre-compiler needs the connection to an Oracle DB which contains the tables you use in the queries into the .pc file(s) that you have to pre-compile.

Comment: ok. Does that mean, I need to compile using pro*c compiler on the same machine that the Oracle DB is hosted on?

Comment: Yes, or on a machine that is connected to that DB, or a machine that has a copy of the table in the DB.

Comment: Furthermore, I remember you might use some templates. But I don't remember very good. I use pro-c, but I've remote connection (via VPN) to DB I use to develop code. In the pro-c manual should be specifications.